# Why is rails-api returning a 500 internal server error instead of 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http-status-code-404, rails-api

Using `rails-api` :

```
  def show
    render json: Room.find(params[:id])
  end
```

This works when the resource is found.  But looking for one that doesn't exist returns a 500 error.  Shouldn't this return 404?

````
> http --json GET chat.dev/api/v1/rooms/23
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Request-Id: 4cd2ba9f-0f85-4530-9c0a-0ef427ac5b31
X-Runtime: 0.094633

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /api/v1/rooms/23
================================================

> Couldn't find Room with id=23

app/controllers/api/v1/rooms_controller.rb, line 20
---------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
   15         #     render :json => {}, :status => :not_found
   16         #   end
   17         # end
   18   
   19         def show
>  20           render json: Room.find(params[:id])
   21         end
   22   
   23       end
   24   
   25     end
````

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not more insightful, but the error returns as 500 instead of 404 when the response is through json. I don't remember the reason why but I remember is has to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into the same thing. In regular Rails, not rails-api. Hope to come up with something better, but so far I just do (as hinted above):

```
def show
  render json: Room.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render json: {}, status: :not_found
end
```

I suppose this is reasonable if you think about Rails' "rescue and return 404 only in production" feature as a convenient default, but when you care more about status codes, you need to get your hands (and code) a bit dirty.

Comment: Not ideal I agree. But if that's the best there is to do, then so be it!

Comment: Turns out I only got this in Rails (3.2.12) because I use the `better_errors` plugin. That one will give a 500 for `RecordNotFound`. Without that plugin, Rails itself *will* actually use a 404 status with that error backtrace. `ActionController::RoutingError` incidentally gives a 404 in either case (Rails catches it before it gets to `better_errors` at all).

Comment: …and it looks like `better_errors` coincidentally [fixed this yesterday](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/commit/5208509aff14a954a7078c55752c3448c13d6728).

Comment: If you want to avoid rescuing you can use Room.find_by(id: params[:id]) and maybe || that with {} - however that won't send the 404 back but an empty record instead.

Answer (score 1):

500 internal server error is returned whenever there is an exception on the server. 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound is an exception, so it returns 500.

Comment: When you are using the standard `rails` stack, it somehow knows to render a 404 page when an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is raised. I had assumed that the behaviour would be the same in `rails-api`  .... i.e. a `RecordNotFound` exception would automatically return `json: {}, status: :not_found` .... Do you know why it does not work this way?